# Get center of any UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, center

I'm trying to write a global function that adds an activityIndicator to any view (mostly imageViews though) by calling such function.

The function I have right now is made of:

```
public func addActivityIndicatorToView(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView, view: UIView){

    //activityIndicator configuration ...
    activityIndicator.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

But I don't get the center of the view for some reason.

I've also tried various solutions around SO and Google, but none worked until now.

Is there any way to get the center point and set the activityIndicator to any UIView?

Comment: If none of the solutions in @EmilioPelaez answer work, I would suggest checking the size of your view. In which method are you setting the activity indicator's center?

Comment: In a global class, which contains all the methods shared across the project

Comment: You could be setting the position of the `activityIndicator` before the view's frame has been setup correctly (in `viewDidLoad` for example)...

Comment: `println("activityIndicator.center before  = \(activityIndicator.center.x) x \(activityIndicator.center.y)")
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
        println("activityIndicator.center after  = \(activityIndicator.center.x) x \(activityIndicator.center.y)")`
show that center have changed. I would think about refreshing problems, not centering.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Original Answer:

I had reproduce your problem easily (see my comment).
I think it could be a problem of auto layout. So may be you can use constraints instead calculate position ?

```
func addActivityIndicatorToView(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView, view: UIView){

    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    //Don't forget this line
    activityIndicator.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


    activityIndicator.startAnimating()


}
```

#### Updated Code for Swift 5.0:

- From edit by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073654/rob)
- `NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX` is now `NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX`
- `NSLayoutRelation.Equal` is now `NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal`
- `NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY` is now `NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY`

```
func addActivityIndicatorToView(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView, view: UIView){

    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    //Don't forget this line
    activityIndicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: activityIndicator, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks to your comment and this amazing piece of code. It's working fine now.

Comment: It's definitely more universal solution then others that use view.center

Comment: this wont work if you have one view controller that has it's view under the navigation bar and one that doesn't

Comment: There was an edit in review, that attempted to change your original answer with the new methods.  I felt it was a useful addendum so it's been added in **Updated Code for Swift 5.0**.  Please review it and roll back to the original answer if you don't think its helpful.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3:

```
activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: view.width/2, y: view.height/2)
```

or you can try:

```
activityIndicator.center = view.center
```

Comment: It's not a center if activityIndicator is not a child of view and view is not located at 0;0.

Answer (score 8):

The `center` property is relative to a view's superview. So if your view's frame is `{10, 10, 20, 20}`, `center` is going to be `{20, 20}`.

I'm guessing you want to center the `activityIndicator` in `view`.

You can do

```
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(view.width/2, view.height/2)
```

Comment: I've already tried that, and unfortunately this goes in the bottom right corner of the superview :(

Comment: how {20, 20 } ? can you explain

Comment: @saurabhgoyal795 the center is the origin plus half the size.